# Downloading WSDL from URL already containing ?wsdl

Tags: soap, wsdl

I'm currently working on something that uses a SOAP API and I'm having difficulty getting the WSDL file for the node SOAP package I'm using.

I have the server information and URL, but I'm not able to download a WSDL file, only an XML one. The provided URL ends: main.asmx?wsdl, so why is it that I don't get a WSDL file?

Comment: Isn't WSDL by definition XML?

Comment: I think. I haven't worked with WSDL/XML before, so I'm not sure. But from what I gather, I'm supposed to have a WSDL file to draw info from, not XML.